# Python - passing random seed (generator) to `randn()`

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, random-seed

I was reading [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-using-numpy-random-seed-581a9972805f) blog post and they suggest that rather than setting the random seed for the whole document

```
np.random.seed(1234)
x = np.random.randn(100)
```

One should use a generator, which can be created as such

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(1234)
```

In the post they use the example of `rng.rand(10)` which works fine. I need to use `randn()` however and it doesn't work if you use `rng.randn(10)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rng.normal(10)` instead.

The [normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.normal.html#numpy.random.Generator.normal) method is the equivalent of `randn`  but using a random generator instance.